# Is there a popular journal of advances in Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, publishing

I enjoy reading the news articles in Nature, which cover the entire physical sciences, from Bioinformatics to Machine Learning. Unfortunately, research in Mathematics and Logic is not covered. Does the Mathematics community publish something similar?

If the question is off-topic, I would gratefully appreciate suggestions where it should be asked.

Comment: Hello! Do you know about [Quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/)?

Comment: There's also [Nautilus](http://nautil.us), which occasionally publishes articles about mathematical research.

Comment: It might not be quite what you're looking for, but [Notices of the American Mathematical Society](https://www.ams.org/notices) often has expository articles for non-specialists about recent advances.

Comment: Quanta looks perfect! Nautilus only has [34 Math articles](http://nautil.us/term/f/Math) in 63 issues.

Comment: Well, the journal called Advances in Mathematics does actually seem fairly popular, though not in the sense that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/)

*"Quanta Magazine is an editorially independent online publication launched by the Simons Foundation to enhance public understanding of science."*

It's free, up-to-date, intelligent, and very readable. Some of the articles appear in Wired, Scientific American, or Nautilus.

Thanks to [Matthew Leingang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2785/matthew-leingang) for pointing this out.